# Oscillator circuit using PNP transistors

Tags: transistors, oscillator, switching, pnp

I'm trying to build an oscillator circuit by using PNP transistors, so I would like to know if this circuit make sense, if it will work.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you meant to start with the traditional two-transistor multivibrator circuit, but swapped around diodes for capacitors, and got the transistors the wrong way around. Simply start with the normal circuit, swap polarity (NPN for PNP), and swap polarity (reverse the supply).

Comment: Aside from the component positions making sense or not, I'm not sure the emitter-coupled approach will work since the gain of each transistor will be less than 1.

Comment: thanks for help. you said (gain of each transistor will be less than 1), what you mean by 1?

Comment: The real number 1. If you don't have overall voltage gain it's hard for oscillations to be sustained.

Comment: OK, i understand.
i have a bunch of PNP transistors and i never used them, so i want to start using them, so i want to ask you, does PNP transistors are useful for multivibrator circuits as same like NPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PNP emitter-followers will not work:
[image: PNP]